# How can I gather the diff between two folders (only the diff) into a different location

Tags: windows-7, music, diff

Basically, what I want to do is find the difference between two music folders (structure example below), and copy that diff to a different location.

Structure of content for both folders:

```
Album artist > Album name
             > Album name 2...
```

*I have two music collections, but I don't want to merge them yet.  I only want to find the difference from one to other, and copy those diffs to a different location.

Answer (score 3):

[winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) is mainly for comparing files, but can also compare directory content